# Mac Automator - "Move finder items" using variable

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I have a weird issue with mac automator (on Mojave).

- **What I want:** Take a pdf > save each page as png to same folder as pdf
- **What happens:** Takes a pdf > all pngs are saved to desktop

Here is the automator after a test run:

[image: Automator Set tup]

You can see on the screenshot how variable "pdfPath" actually is set correctly to Test folder. But then after moving it does remove the files out of system folder, but not to pdfPath but to Desktop. Important: if I manually pick any folder, it will save it there and not to desktop, so still somehow related to the pdfPath variable?

Anybody an idea why it happens and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Automator just gets frustrating like this at times.  The **Move Finder Items** action doesn’t appear to work with variables in this situation, even though you can drag and select them - when using a variable it defaults to the Desktop.  As a workaround you can replace the **Move Finder Items** action with a **Get Value of Variable** for `pdfPath` to add it to the input items, then add a **Run AppleScript** action to do the moving:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  if (count input) < 2 then error "No Items to move.“
  set destination to last item of input
  tell application "Finder" to move (items 1 thru -2 of input) to destination
end run
```

You might also have to clean out previous results from the temporary folder to keep the rename action happy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out with some help in the meantime. For anybody coming across and looking for solution, the path I saved in the Applescript part was showing up nicely in the result, but in the end, the path was in the wrong format. Following code works like a charm:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder" to return POSIX path of (container of (item 1 of input) as alias) as text
end run
```

Comment: You can also use `(container of item 1 of input) as alias`, but you shouldn't have to convert Finder items, especially for Finder actions.

Comment: @Silver thank you - this is very helpful. The one challenge I have is that I can't specify the PDFpath variable I created as the path in the final Move Finder Items step. The path dropdown only allows for selecting an existing folder or creating a new variable. Any idea what might be causing this?